# How to transform an array of objects into fields in the parent object in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection where every document has this kind of structure:

```
{
  docName: "Document Name",
  probabilities: [
            { topicName:"topic1", prob: 0.3  },
            { topicName:"topic2", prob: 0.4  }, 
            { topicName:"topic3", prob: 0.23 }
              ...
            ]
 otherField: data,
 ...
}
```

I need to trnaform them into something like this:

```
{
  docName: "Document Name",
  topic1: 0.3,
  topic2: 0.4, 
  topic3: 0.23,
  ...
  otherField: data,
  ...
}
```

I tried using $arrayToObject and $objectToArray but I didn't figure out how to make it work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        "$$ROOT",
        { "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$probabilities",
            "in": {
              "k": "$$this.topicName",
              "v": "$$this.prob"
            }
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "probabilities": 0 }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zuw7My29n4u)